# Re-direct problem with HTACCESS edit

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tsgcs.ca$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.tsgcs.ca/$1 [R=301,L]

This is giving me errors 'Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.'

Any ideas why?

Comment: You're sure that there aren't any other rules defined?

Comment: *tsgcs.ca* is being redirected to *www.tsgcs.ca* and that is being redirected back to *tsgcs.ca* (see http://web-sniffer.net/).

Comment: That's the only redirect rule i think, @Gumbo how would i stop that?

Comment: Maybe there is another rule in your server/virtual host configuration. You should probably ask your provider about that.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to redirect the non-www version of a URL to the www version. It's almost correct, but the matching in the RewriteRule isn't quite right. Take a look at the examples here:

http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml